# Liquid to solid when exposed to air

Tags: mixtures

Is there a liquid mixture that will become a solid when exposed to air/oxygen. Preferably a spongy material that is difficult to tear.

Answer (score 3):

Urethane foam from isocyanates, commonly sold at hardware stores for insulation.

Click links for [general information](http://www.spraypolyurethane.org/Main-Menu-Category/Do-It-Yourself/Frequently-Asked-Questions) and for [its chemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane).